# Laravel 5.0: How to filter the collection results based on status

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a database of machines, i want them to hide when the status = "disabled", i know about soft delete but i still want the admins to have access to those machines even tho they wont show up on this specific view, so they can't be deleted.

here's the controller function

```
    public function home(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    switch ($user->tipo) {
        case 'admin':
            $title = 'Máquinas';
            $maquinas = Maquinas::all();
            $admin = true;
            break;
        case 'cliente':
            $cliente = Clientes::find($user->cliente_id);
            $title = $cliente->empresa.' <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="font-size: 20px; color: gray"></i> Máquinas';
            $maquinas = $cliente->maquinas()->get();
            $admin = false;
            break;
        case 'base':
            $cliente = Clientes::find($user->cliente_id);
            $base = Bases::find($user->base_id);
            $title = $cliente->empresa.' <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="font-size: 20px; color: gray"></i> '.$base->nome.' <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" style="font-size: 20px; color: gray"></i> Máquinas';
            $maquinas = $base->maquinas()->get();
            $admin = false;
            break;
        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
```

i want to filter the disabled ones on case 'cliente' and case 'base'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to chain the `where` function into the query, assuming you have a column for status.

```php
$maquinas = $cliente->maquinas()->where('status', '!=', 'disabled')->get();
```

[Laravel Docs for the Query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for the help! i was trying really hard to do a makeHidden in the Model for some reason

Comment: No worries @AndréFreitas
As a suggestion, I would look at using relationships for the `Clientes` and `Bases` instead, and just call something like `$user->base` instead.